# ANN, most similar results based on vector space

Tags: algorithm, search, vector, neural-network

Example: the ANN is taught attributes of a car (engine, color, tires, etc.).

The input are some parameters (diesel, red, R17, ..).

The output are taught cars ordered by how similar they are to the input, even with no exact matches.

I remember, that it has to do with vector space (the attributes represents the vectors). I am planning on working with 20+ such attributes (vectors).

What is the name of this algorithm / neural network type and where can I learn more?

Thank You

Comment: You can use multilayer perceptron (http://cs.du.edu/~mitchell/mario_books/Neural_Networks_for_Pattern_Recognition_-_Christopher_Bishop.pdf - chapter 4)

Comment: I think you mean a convolutional neural network (https://www.google.nl/search?q=convolutional+network&source=lnms&tbm=isch) which is trained to recognize multiple patterns through a convolutional layer

Comment: Please do not be confused with image recognition. I am going to work just with the textual data.